# Beautifulsoup css data extraction

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to extract css data from an html document.
the data points are a variable number of circle x-y coordinates generated by the user onto an image and exported into the html as follows:

```
#shapes a#rage_circle1{
    top: 248px;
    left: 231px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-image: none;
}
```

I would like an output of the top and left pixel numbers.

UPDATED:

this is what I have done so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup (open ('index.html'))
x= soup.findAll(text=re.compile('left'))
print (x)
```

The output generated is all the data between the braces above and is not selecting the "left" string only. I am not sure why my script is not selecting a particular data between the braces. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well you could use regular expressions, and I think BeautifulSoup.find_all() can take a regex as input.

Comment: I think https://code.google.com/p/soupselect/ for BeautifulSoup is useful. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716181/beautifulsoup-but-for-css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [cssutils](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/) is the right choice for your problem. The following snippet will simply output the values of all `top` and `left` attributes.

```
import cssutils
css = cssutils.parseFile('index.html')
for rule in css.cssRules:
    print(rule.style.top)
    print(rule.style.left)
```

Comment: Thank you for this Regex was proving to be too complicated for the task that I was intending to do. Some errors are being thrown but at least it is a start.