# Unable to crawl CSS to HTML with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm try to crawl the correct CSS to go with the html table created from beautifulsoup. The table is done but CSS is not. Can anyone take a look at my code and perhaps suggeste a better way to crawl stylesheet?

I can see two issues:
1. I'm not locating the correct stylesheet on the page matching the table
2. My implementation of the CSS into the html file is awkward if not any issues.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os
import tabulate
import urllib.request
import io
from bs4 import Comment


url = "https://www.etax.nat.gov.tw/etw-main/web/ETW183W2_10805/"

url_css = "https://www.etax.nat.gov.tw/etwmain/resources/web/css/main.fia.css"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), features="html.parser",from_encoding='utf-16')

soup_table = soup.findAll('table')[0]

soup_css = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url_css).read(), features="html.parser",from_encoding='utf-16')

with io.open("soup_table.html", "w", encoding='utf-16') as f:
   f.write(str(soup_table))
   f.write("<script>")
   f.write(str(soup_css))
   f.write("</script>")
```

There is no error message, just that the table doesn't look right without properly styling.

Comment: Shouldn't the css be in `<style>` and not in `<script>`?

Comment: BeautifulSoup parses html. If the css is not inline, you can't parse it the same way. check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716181/beautifulsoup-but-for-css) for a possible solutions

Comment: Read about in section [Internal Style Sheet](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_style_sheet.htm) how it have to look.